Issue with Login Redirection on Vercel
When I'm working locally, it works fine, but as soon as I deploy to production,
I'm unable to log in. Why is it redirecting to localhost even on the Vercel domain?
When I'm trying to access the vercel domain URL and trying to login, After login Google Login Page redirects me to "http://localhost:3000/?code=032ca21e-27c1-4142-8849-525294ab3033"


You haven't provided any code here or even what your redirect url you are passing to the signInWithOAuth looks like. You need to provide more information than this when asking these sorts of questions.
